# Identify this houseplant please?

Tags: houseplants, foliage

Edit: I don't think it's a **peace lily** because it's never flowered, the leaves are not as wide or shiny/waxy, and the venation is less dense.

It's been through the ringer, neglected by ex-wife, but keeps springing back.  I need to add soil, repot.  Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is a peace lily or spathiphyllum

Comment: Kept in kitchen? Plant might not like the grease and fumes.

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger, no just for trimming dead leaves and these pics.